# The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: npm, build, gulp, node-sass

When I install node_modules using `npm install`, I face this error.

```
D:\react\...\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project  
"D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I've installed Visual Studio Build Tools.

MSBuild position is `c:\Program File (x86)\MSBuild`

And I set VCTargetsPath as `$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0@VCTargetsPath)` on regedit on path
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0`

But I am not sure why the path to be `D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if the path registered on the registry.
[Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0]

```
Name: VCTargetsPath
Type: REG_SZ
Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

If it doesn't work for you, add a path to the system environment path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets
```

Hope to work for you.